# ¿Cómo hacer que un div ocupe el 100% sin sobre ponerse?

Tags: html, css

Necesito que solo ocupe el espacio entre el `div` de arriba y el `div` de abajo pero sin sobreponerse utilizo `height:100%;` con un margen por arriba pero entonces el `div` "contenido" queda encima del que esta abajo

```css
.arriba{
position:fixed;
top:0px;
heigh:30px;
width:100%;
}
.abajo{
position:fixed;
top:0px;
heigh:30px;
width:100%;
}
.contenido{
height:100%;
margin-top:30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="arriba">Arriba</div>
<div class="contenido">"contenido"</div>
<div class="abajo">Abajo</div>
```

Comment: Título != Descripción.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Nota**

> Considera que aunque tu maquetación se puede considerar *funcional*, por ejemplo en la sección final o de abajo tendrás problemas para mostrar el contenido que quieras agregar y no se verá completamente por lo que deberás empezar a recurrir a mas reglas CSS como la manejo de los margins para que logres moverlo de su ubicación y mostrarlo; pero al mismo tiempo teniendo cuidado que eso no mueva el resto de tu maquetación.

Dado todo lo anterior propongo:

- Cuando modificas el `position` de las etiquetas HTML las *estás sacando del flujo de acomodo regular que poseen*
- Como estás indicando un `position` distinto al regular necesitas moverlas con las reglas:

  - top
  - left
  - right
  - bottom
- Como a los `div` cuyas clases son arriba y abajo les dejas el `top` en 0 entonces los dos parten de quedar posicionados sin avance desde dicha ubicación y por eso se *enciman*
- En este caso dado el acomodo que deseas lo mejor sería envolver los 3 elementos en un contenedor extra que sea de naturaleza `flex` y lo podamos manipular para que se vea como columnas
- Ahora del 100% del *viewport* lo dividimos en por ejemplo

  - 20% al inicio
  - 60% al contenido
  - 20% al fin
- Cómo los div tienen naturaleza de bloque salvo otra configuración no es necesario dar la indicación de 100%

**EJEMPLO**

```html
    <style>
      body {
        color: white;
        margin: 0;
      }
      .contenedor-secciones {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column
      }
      .arriba {
        height: 20vh;
        background-color: red;
      }
      .contenido {
        height: 60vh;
        background-color: green;
      }
      .abajo {
        height: 20vh;
        background-color: brown;
      }
    </style>
    
    <div class="contenedor-secciones">
      <div class="arriba">Arriba</div>
      <div class="contenido">"contenido"</div>
      <div class="abajo">Abajo</div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo único que te faltaba para poner el `contenido` en medio era poner es div en medio y tenias tu CSS, en la parte de abajo, en tu `position: fixed;`, tenias  `top : 0px;` y eso hace que superponga con el div `arriba`.

```css
.arriba{
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
    height:30px;
    width:100%;
}
.abajo{
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0px;
    height:30px;
    width:100%;
}

.contenido{
        height:100%;
        margin-top:30px;
        }
```

```html
<div class="arriba">Arriba</div>
<div class="contenido">contenido</div>
<div class="abajo">Abajo</div>
```

Espero que esto te sirva.